Unintelligible Error: Never fail FormatException from class _ChunkedJsonParser<T> (convert_patch.dart)
I'm developing my app in Flutter, and I have a search feature that calls a PHP API which interacts with a server to retrieve rows from a database. When I had a local dump of this database and was using my localhost as the server, there were no problems. However, after moving the PHP to the production server, I encounter this error during certain searches:
 Never fail(int position, [String? message]) {
    if (message == null) {
      message = "Unexpected character";
      if (position == chunkEnd) message = "Unexpected end of input";
    }
    throw new FormatException(message, chunk, position);
  }

Exception has occurred.

FormatException (FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 1) ^ )

This code is part of the abstract class _ChunkedJsonParser<T> from convert_patch.dart.
What could be causing this error?
This is one of the codes that calls the API from the search bar:
void getSuggestion() async {
    if (query.length > 2) {
      var res = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(API.search),
        body: {
          "query": query,  // late String query;
        },
      );

      if (res.statusCode == 200) {
        setState(() {
          print(res.body);
          data = jsonDecode(res.body); // var data;
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          error = true;
        });
      }
    } 
  }

Is there any configuration I should check on the server's XAMPP that might differ from my localhost settings, which could explain why it works on mine but not on the production server?
Thanks!
This is how my PHP receives my query:
if (isset($_REQUEST["query"])) 
{
    $query = $connectNow->real_escape_string(strtolower($_REQUEST["query"]));
}

I tried to print the server response, but when I print it with this error, it appears empty.

"Unexpected end of input" means that jsonDecode received an incomplete JSON string.  The "at character 1" means that the string was incomplete at the first character, which means that you're calling jsonDecode on an empty string.

I understand, thank you for responding, but why would the same database, hosted on different servers, show such a discrepancy? Any other advice I should consider?

I'm merely answering your question "What could be causing this error?" Either your Dart code should handle the case of an empty response body or you need to figure out how and why your server could return a response body and guarantee that it won't do that.  I can't tell you why your server is doing that.  Maybe a load issue?  Maybe a permission issue?  You need to do some debugging on your own.
